# I'm having a trouble with lifes system I'm making in a simple text game

Tags: python

```
    def hangman():
    words = ("potato", "pumpkin", "winter", "left", "right", "up")
    ra = (random.choice(words))
    devided = (list(ra))
    lifes = 4

    lenght = (len(devided))
    print ("The word has", lenght, "letters, try to guess it and the first letter is", devided[0])

    answer = input("The word is: ")

    if (answer == ra):
        print ("Correct")
        exit()
    elif (answer != ra):
        lifes -= 1
        while (lifes != 0):
            print ("Wrong, you have", lifes, "lifes left")
            hangman()
hangman()
```

So I made a game in which you have to guess the word from words variable, its pretty simple because it tells you how long the generated random word is and whats the first letter of a word.

Now I'm having a trouble in making a system which when you guess the word wrong you have 1 life less, it does work, it substracts -1 from life variable once you guess wrong but when it loops the variable lifes resets back to lifes = 4 and it should stay 3, how do I save so it doesnt change? So whenever I guess the word wrong the variable keeps going 1 number down until it hits 0 and the loop stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code is a little messed up
the easy fixes would be to change
`while (lifes != 0):` replace `the` `while` with an `if` 
and if you insist on making it run with recursion, pass the lifes as a parameter

remove the line `lifes = 4` and instead change the function definition to:
`def hangman(lifes=4):` (i left it as lifes, but the english word is lives)
then all you have to change is this part
`print ("Wrong, you have", lifes, "lifes left")
            hangman()`

into
`print ("Wrong, you have", lifes, "lifes left")
            hangman(lifes)`

Comment: It worked, thanks for helping me out, also fixed the grammar mistake :P

Would be nice if you could explain me why it didnt work and why does it work now, why was it that while loop kept resetting variable?

Comment: @Towelie the solution you used, uses recursion, this textbox is too small to explain it well so you should read up on that. in simple terms, you call the function again every time the guess is wrong, so you keep running the line `lifes = 4` over and over again.